# How to do transform with click in button

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to make a flip card work through a button, it is working normally with :hover but I cannot make it work with a button. I've tried using jquery and it didn't work can someone help me with this problem? (Im using bootstrap)

```css
.card-flip > div {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.card-flip:hover .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
  
.card-flip:hover .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.test{
 background-color: green;
}

.test2{
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="card card-flip h-100 test">
            <div class="card-front text-white bg-dark">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-search fa-5x float-right"></i>
                    <h3 class="card-title">Front</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-back bg-white test2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Back</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">Suprise this one has more more more more content on the back!</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Action</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I gave you the answer. Please let me know, did you need this?

Answer (score 0):

did you want it? if you wedge on the yellow block, you will go back.

```js
$('.card-flip').on('click', function() {
  $('.card-front').css('transform', 'rotateY(-180deg)');
  $('.card-back').css('transform', 'rotateY(0deg)');
});

$(document).on('click', '.card-back', function() {
  $(this).css('transform', '');
  $('.card-front').css('transform', ''); 
});
```

```css
.card-flip > div {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/*.card-flip:hover .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
  
.card-flip:hover .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}*/

.test{
 background-color: green;
}

.test2{
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="card card-flip h-100 test">
            <div class="card-front text-white bg-dark">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <i class="fa fa-search fa-5x float-right"></i>
                    <h3 class="card-title">Front</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-back bg-white test2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Back</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">Suprise this one has more more more more content on the back!</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Action</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```